# Time's up, it's over

Tags: riddle, word

> If I'm on, it's not time;
>   If I have time, it's up;
>   If I'm up, it's over;
>   If I'm over, it's dizzying.

What am I?

Comment: The way you have linked the clues to each other is outrageously brilliant.

Comment: @Bass Don't make me blush

Comment: Terrific riddle. A lot of outstanding wordplay packed in so nicely. Kudos.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Second go  as this is still up

> hang

If I'm on, it's not time;

> hang on - wait a little

If I have time, it's up;

> hang time - when an object is up in the air, as in a basketball player off the court

If I'm up, it's over;

> hang up - stop the phone call as it's over

If I'm over, it's dizzying.

> hangover - a dizzying experience after overdoing alcohol

---

First try was this play on a word might be a

> game

If I'm on, it's not time;

> game on  - anticipation that an event is going to happen

If I have time, it's up;

> game time - the event is happening

If I'm up, it's over;

> game up - it's done and revealed

If I'm over, it's dizzying.

> game over - said when a situation is regarded as hopeless

Comment: Your framework is right but the guess isn't quite right. The intended answer unmistakably factors in "dizzying"

Comment: Second go is it! Nicely done

Comment: Thank you @anodyne for the nicely related clues in this puzzle, and you're right that the first answer wasn't close enough for the last clue.